# Can a single thread be shared among multiple processes ? If yes how?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

Each process can have multiple threads , but **is it allowed that single thread can be shared among multiple processes ?** I have confusion that i am relating this to tightly coupled multiprocessor where memory is shared among multiple processor.

In tightly coupled multiprocessor : memory is shared
In loosely coupled multiprocessor : distributed memory

Correct me if i am thinking in wrong direction.

Comment: You're thinking in the wrong direction. A thread belongs to a process.

Comment: Not in any modern OS or programming language that I am aware of.  There is nothing preventing it.  It just isn't done usually.

Comment: A thread is generated and owned by a process.  It cannot be shared.  There are a whole lot of security considerations that make doing so a bit of a nightmare.  Best to save thread state somewhere that can be accessed by another process.

Comment: You mean "processors", not "processes"?

Comment: @RobertMcKee Imagine a single  island that exists in more than one lake.  There is nothing preventing it...

Comment: @jameslarge For simplicity, I'll just let this one slide and say in JAVA, threads can't be shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right that accidentally you were thinking in wrong direction.

Now, to start with answer to your confusion, whether it tightly coupled or loosely coupled multi-core or single-core processor etc. etc., **in Java a thread will belong to the same process for its life time**.

- The process to which the thread belongs may be parked by the processor to give time to some other process, which would mean that thread is also not active.
- The thread may be parked by the process to give priority over some other thread. This is exactly what you call as thread priorities.

You can take advantage of multi-core processors using Java's [fork/join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) by using all available processors for thread execution. But in this case as well, whether a thread is being executed by one processor or other, **thread will stick tightly to the process in which it started it life.**